# Python daemon doesnt spawn at times

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-daemon

I have a daemon in python which I spawn using DaemonRunner API(a PID file and lock file are created). The PID file and lock file are deleted when the daemon is stopped.

The start/stop works fine except sometimes the daemon doesn't start. I need to delete the entire folder which had the PID file to get it back up. How do I debug this? Also there is a auto-generated file with the name HOST.MainThread-PID. What is the significance of this?

Here's my class to start/stop daemon

```
class MyRunner(DaemonRunner):
    def __init__(self,appl):
        self.appl = appl
        DaemonRunner.__init__(self,appl)

    def start(self):
        // Check if PID file exists..
        retval =DaemonRunner.start(self)
        return retval

    def stop(self):
        return DaemonRunner.stop(self)
```

strace looks similar for both the successful and unsuccessful usecases.

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: You have to list the files contained in the directory where PID file is stored that seems to solve the issue when deleted. You have to consistently test the script with the same user over and over. Observe the behavior when the directory is owned by another user and you attempt to run the daemon as a different user.

Comment: I have added the class I use to start/stop the daemon